# pd.to_datetime converting mixed object feature column value to NAT values but intend to extract month

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series, data-cleaning

I've been trying to process a column date in the Dataframe to obtain the month in int type using `pd.to_datetime`.

This is the code in Python using pandas .

```
print(df["date"].head())
```

```
0       Oct
1       Jun
2    15-Oct
3    27-Nov
4    26-Sep
Name: date, dtype: object
```

After attempting to convert to datetime,I obtained all values in NAT. How do I fix this?

```
df["date"]=pd.to_datetime(df["date"],errors='coerce')
print(df["date"].head())
```

I get:

```
0   NaT
1   NaT
2   NaT
3   NaT
4   NaT

Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Running isNA returns all values at NAT:

```
print(df["date"].isna().sum())
1000
```

I plan to obtain:

```
0       10
1       06
2       10
3       11
4       09
```

For values that can't be converted to datetime and then int(because values are missing or unrecognisable) I plan to replace with "Date not given"

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {'Jan':'01', 'Feb':'02','Mar':'03', 'Apr':'04', 
     'May':'05','Jun':'06', 'Jul':'07','Aug':'08',
     'Sep':'09', 'Oct':'10', 'Nov':'11', 'Dec':'12'}

df["date1"] = df["date"].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False).map(d)
```

Or convert values to datetimes with `%b` for match months and convert to strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["date2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False), 
                             format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%m')
print (df)
     date date1 date2
0     Oct    10    10
1     Jun    06    06
2  15-Oct    10    10
3  27-Nov    11    11
4  26-Sep    09    09
```

If need integers:

```
print (df)
     date
0    Ocyt
1     Jun
2  15-Oct
3  27-Nov
4  26-Sep


df["date2"] = (pd.to_datetime(df["date"].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+)', expand=False), 
                              format='%b', errors='coerce')
                 .dt.month.astype('Int64'))
print (df)
     date  date2
0    Ocyt   <NA>
1     Jun      6
2  15-Oct     10
3  27-Nov     11
4  26-Sep      9
```

Comment: since `map` ignores the no-match case, method #1 still gives `NaN` in case of an invalid month name, while method #2 throws an Exception - or is there a "must map" method?

Comment: @FObersteiner - thanks, I change second solution for same ouput `NaN`s if no match

Answer (score 1):

You can split your columns on '-' and keep the last part:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.split('-').str[-1], format='%b', errors='coerce').dt.month
0    10
1     6
2    10
3    11
4     9
Name: date, dtype: int32
```

If your locale is not English, you can use:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'C')
```